# Hover not working properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have a problem with my jquery hover in desktop view. every time I hover out (mouse out) the parent nav the subpage won't close, after I hover'out the subpages stays open. How to fix this hover that when every time I hover out the subpages will also hide.

I'm using this codes

```
jQuery('.dropdown').hover(function(){
    if(!jQuery('.navbar-toggle').is(':visible')) { // disable for mobile view
        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('open')) { // Keeps it open when hover it again
            jQuery('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

Please see the image for better visualization

[image]

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not get back auto with `mouseout` .You need assign some function of [`mouseout`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiw0dfJ15zUAhXJMo8KHb6oDx4QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fmouseout%2F&usg=AFQjCNGZObzC6z56xBTJomwX-1ygY5vPBw&sig2=i_Uz5rw83ONY24e0_QfCew) like this

```
jQuery('.dropdown').hover(function(){
    if(!jQuery('.navbar-toggle').is(':visible')) { // disable for mobile view
        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('open')) { // Keeps it open when hover it again
            jQuery('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
jQuery('.dropdown').mouseout(function(){ // for mouse out event
//do stuff
})
```

Or with in [**`hover()`**](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
jQuery('.dropdown').hover(function(){
        if(!jQuery('.navbar-toggle').is(':visible')) { // disable for mobile view
            if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('open')) { // Keeps it open when hover it again
                jQuery('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
            }
        }
    },function(){ // for mouse out event
        jQuery(this).removeClass('open')
    })
```

**working example**

```js
$('a').hover(function(){
$(this).css('color','red')
},function(){
$(this).css('color','black')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>ppp</a>
```

Comment: Yep, was going to suggest the same thing

Comment: Why not assign a handler to the out-action in hover? 
Calling $( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut ) is shorthand for:
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );

Comment: @KeAn .nice .I m not well in `jquery` .For my  approch is `mouseout` .gentral concept from native js

Comment: Guy's what should I put on jQuery('.dropdown').mouseout(function(){? sorry for the noob question

Comment: @MelvinRey you can do with  `or` hover method .i was apply the `removeClass('open')` only .I was not correct with respected element to hide without seen your snippet html code .just try and if not post the snippet html code

Comment: @prasad I tried the second code "Or with in hover()" and it works perfectly! as smooth as awesome! Thank you... Big thanks!!! :)